# I am getting the following error"for line in f(list): TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable" while running the below python code

Tags: python, csv, date-range, python-3.6

```
import os,csv,datetime,list

startingtime = input('starting time:')
endtime=input('end time:')

with open('csvfile.csv') as f:
   list=[f,startingtime,endtime]
   for line in f(list):
      print(line)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code? What is an example input and example output for what you want to do? Please [edit] your question to provide more information and use proper formatting.

Comment: `f` does not have a `__call__` method defined, so you can't do `f(list)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call `f` with `f(list)`. Don't do that. `f` is a file handle, not a function. Also, avoid declaring variables that share a name with a keyword like `list`. I'm not sure what you're doing with `list` or your CSV file, but this might help if you're trying to write startingtime and endtime to a single row CSV file.

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
   mylist = [startingtime, endtime]
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(mylist)
```

See here for a tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

[Output expected: Need to print lines from starting to endtime mentioned by user. Say for example, from 5:18 to 5:20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcfrI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely sorry was not writing the question clearly.Below is the similar csv file which I need to access.In each line it will have time mentioned(5:18 to 5:22 in 5th column).My question is, i need to get input(start time and end time) and print the entire lines which is having 5:18 to 5:21. That is, if i give start time as 5:19 and end time as 5:21. It should print the entire lines from 2nd row to 4th row.

aaaaa   lshds   dslkd   dslkd       5:18        ss

dslkd     lsh2d   dslkd    dslkd    5:19        dd

lshds   lshds   lshds   lshds       5:20        dd

aaaaa   dslkd   dslka   dslkd       5:21        dase

dslkd   dslkd   dslkd   dslkd       5:22        daew